# Call nix-build when files in a directory change?

Tags: compilation, nix

Stack has

```
stack build --file-watch
```

which automatically recompiles a Haskell project whenever files change.  Does nix have something analogous with `nix-build`, or is there a well-known tool which can help achieve these?

Comment: Not a feature of `nix-build`, but perhaps a different tool could be used to call `nix-build`, such as these suggestions:  "FAQ: I want to run arbitrary commands when arbitrary files change..." https://github.com/ndmitchell/ghcid#i-want-to-run-arbitrary-commands-when-arbitrary-files-change

Comment: For Haskell and Nix this https://stackoverflow.com/q/67312833/1007926 may be relevant

Answer (score 1):

Nix does not provide this functionality by itself. [Lorri](https://github.com/target/lorri) comes close, but its focus is on providing an instant "nix-shell" via [direnv](https://github.com/zimbatm/direnv). It is not currently suitable for building and testing your project like `stack build --file-watch` does. If you're interested, you could create an issue to discuss such a feature with the authors.

Comment: I haven't seen any.